# Difference between Class and Class<?>

Tags: java, generics

What is the difference between a `Class` and a `Class<?>` declaration.

- `Class a;`
- `Class<?> b;`

Answer (score 47, accepted):

It's the same as with all generic and raw types:

```
Class          // An unknown class (raw type)
Class<?>       // An unknown class (generic version)
Class<String>  // The String class
```

In this special case there's not much practical difference between `Class` and `Class<?>` because they both denote an unknown class. Depending on the existing declarations the compiler can demand a generic type instead of a raw type.

**But:** Since Java 1.5 you should use the generic form wherever possible. `Class<?>` clearly states that you mean "an unknown class", `Class<String>` cleary states that you mean the `String` class. A raw `Class` could mean *both*.

In the end it makes not much of a difference to the compiler but it makes a huge difference in making the intentions of your code more understandable and maintainable.

Comment: You should avoid using rules without explanations wherever possible.

Answer (score 11):

Class [javadoc](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html):

> **Type Parameters:**
>   `T` - the type of the class modeled by this `Class` object. For example, the type of `String.class` is `Class<String>`. Use `Class<?>` if the class being modeled is unknown.

Use of `Class` without the type parameter is similar to using any generic class (`Map`, `List`, etc.) without the type parameter - either it's a pre-1.5 legacy usage or it's just a segment of code that does not care about unchecked type casting.

Answer (score 3):

Class`<?>` shows that you're intentionally writing Java 5-level code that doesn't know or care what class you are dealing with. Leaving out the  makes it look like old code or code written by someone who hasn't learned generics yet.

Answer (score 1):

"it look like old code or code written by someone who hasn't learned generics yet." This is an correct statement.  Class  (pronounced "class of unknown"), that is, a class whose  type matches anything. It's called a wild-card type for obvious reasons.

for example:

```
public void drawAll(List<Shape> shapes) {
    for (Shape s: shapes) {
        s.draw(this);
   }
}
```

type rules say that drawAll() can only be called on lists of exactly `Shape`: it cannot, for instance, be called on, say, a `List<Circle>`. That is unfortunate, since all the method does is read shapes from the list, so it could just as well be called on a `List<Circle>`.

What we really want is for the method to accept a list of any kind of shape.

```
public void drawAll (List <? extends Shape> shapes) {

}
```

read more: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html